# bash - output command to variable not working

Tags: linux, bash

For some reason this is not working on my machine. I have a test script `test.sh` containing

```
#! /usr/bin/env ksh
JV=$(javac -version)
echo "JV1: $JV eol"
echo "JV2: ${JV} eol"
```

Output

```
JV1:  eol
JV2:  eol
```

If I run command on terminal

```
>: javac -version
```

I get

```
>: javac 1.8.0_222
```

---

Environment:

*OS: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908*

*Bash: 4.2.46(2)*

---

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash), doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: It works as expected for me.

Comment: What do you see if you put `javac -version` in the script itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java -version` is writing to standard error, not standard output (which is what `$(...)` captures. You need to redirect the output.

```
JV=$(javac -version 2>&1)
```

Comment: whoa.. didn't knew that, works now